# How to interchange two non-fubini infinite summations?

Tags: calculus, summation

I wish to prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i, n}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{i, n}$$
($a_{i,n}$ is not strictly positive)
for the case where $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left|a_{i,\ n}\right|=\infty.$$
Hence, the Fubini theorem cannot be used. With this in mind, what other theorems could be used to rigorously justify when the summations can be interchanged?

It is worth noting that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i,\ n}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{i,\ n}$ both converge, just not when the absolute value is taken.

Comment: You cannot prove a **false** statement.

Comment: You can sum in any order whenever the terms are nonnegative, or whenever $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \max[a_{i,n},0]<\infty$ or $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \max[-a_{i,n},0]<\infty$.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for your response. Is there a name for that theorem?

Comment: The non-negative Fubini has been called Tonelli's theorem before

Comment: @tough-05-accrual : Aside from Fubini-Tonelli, I have not seen the material I gave in my answer in other sources, that exposition is mine.  It just seems like reasonable material that is easy to prove. One reason it may not be in textbooks is that sometimes it is easier to just define a sum when it is finite, and say infinite sums are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $\mathbb{N}=\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

**Def:** The *ordered sum* is defined
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n b_i$$
whenever the limit on the right-hand-side exists (possibly being $\infty$ or $-\infty$). If the limit on the right-hand-side does not exist then the ordered sum does not exist.

**Def:** The *unordered sum* $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} b_i$ is well defined whenever its corresponding ordered sum exists and is the same regardless of the order in which the terms are summed (the value can possibly be $\infty$ or $-\infty$).

**Claim 1:** If $b_n\geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then  $\sum_{n \in\mathbb{N}} b_i$ is well defined (possibly $\infty$).

This is a special case of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

**Claim 2:** $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} b_n$ is well defined (possibly $\infty$ or $-\infty$) if and only if either
$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \max[b_n,0]<\infty$$
or
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \max[-b_n,0]< \infty$$

**Proof:** First suppose both sums are $\infty$. Then the sum over the nonnegative terms is $\infty$ and the sum over the negative terms is $-\infty$. We can put the nonnegative terms in a sequence $\{p_i\}$ and the negative terms in a sequence $\{n_i\}$ and then interlace them in a particular order to make the ordered sum either $\infty$ or $-\infty$. So the sum is not independent of order.

To prove the reverse direction, define $U,V \in [0, \infty]$ by
\begin{align*}
U &= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \max[b_n,0]\\
V &= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \max[-b_n,0]
\end{align*}
Assume that $V<\infty$ (the case $U<\infty$ is similar). We want to show that for any ordering, the ordered sum exists and is the same regardless of order.  For each $i$ we have
$$ b_i = \max[b_i,0]  - \max[-b_i,0]$$
Let $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be any bijection. Then for any positive integer $m$:
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=1}^{m} b_{g(k)} &= \sum_{k=1}^n\max[b_{g(k)},0] - \sum_{k=1}^n\min[-b_{g(k)},0]\\
&\geq \sum_{k=1}^n\max[b_{g(k)},0] - V
\end{align}
Taking a $\liminf$ of both sides gives
$$ \liminf_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^m b_{g(k)} \geq U-V \quad (Eq *)$$
Now if $U=\infty$ we are done:
$$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^m b_{g(k)} = \infty$$
(and this is the same for all bijections $g$).

Now suppose $U<\infty$. Then both $U<\infty$ and $V<\infty$ and
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=1}^{m} b_{g(k)} &= \sum_{k=1}^m\max[b_{g(k)},0] - \sum_{k=1}^m\min[-b_{g(k)},0]\\
&\leq U - \sum_{k=1}^n\min[-b_{g(k)},0]
\end{align}
Taking a $\limsup$ gives
$$ \limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^mb_{g(k)} \leq U - V$$
which from Eq * gives
$$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^mb_{g(k)} = U-V$$
(regardless of the bijection $g$)
$\Box$